# Calculate compass heading to a CLLocation - Haversine functions for iOS

Tags: iphone, mapkit, core-location, haversine

I understand how to get the distance between 2 CLLocations. I need to determine the generalized compass bearing (N, NE, E etc.) from a CLLocation to another CLLocation.

Before I implement something to derive the bearing with the haversine formula is there a generally adapted open source library or code fragment that you've found solves this problem with or without using haversine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used some of the snippets available from [Movable Type Scripts](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) - both haversine and spherical law of cosines available. The code examples are all in JavaScript, but they translate very easily to C or Objective C.

Comment: Cool. Thanks just wasn't sure if there was another way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/100grams/CoreLocationUtils

Comment: I rolled my own haversine but your work on this library looks great. Thanks for sharing. Neat dead reckoning work.

Comment: most of the functions are deprecated Now in this Library.